# I am trying to ignore a trigger field in a Postgres update trigger

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers

I have a trigger set up to update a last_edit_date column, and I am trying to ignore a last_access_date column as it's updated every time the page is visited, which triggers the "last_edited" trigger to fire because it views the update as an edit.  I am trying the following code for the trigger, but receiving the following error :

> pg_execute(): Query failed: ERROR:  column "last_access_date" does not exist

Here's the code -

```
BEGIN
 IF NOT (UPDATE(last_access_date))
 THEN
  NEW.last_edit_date := now();
  RETURN NEW;
 END IF;
END;
```

Also, the column DOES exist, but it's a column tied to triggers (not sure if that matters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore all updates that modify `last_access_date`, you can use:

```
IF NEW.last_access_date = OLD.last_access_date THEN
   NEW.last_edit_date = current_timestamp;
END IF;
```

Aside: `last_access_date` makes me nervous, since many updates are bad for PostgreSQL. Make sure that there is no index on the column and that the `fillfactor` for this table is set to less than 100 so you can get HOT updates for this column.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot @LaurenzAlbe.  After purging the triggers and adding them programmatically (instead of pgAdmin 4 UI), that seemed to do the trick.  Also, will read up on HOT updates and see what I can find out. Much appreciated, also thanks richyen